# Text blurring at any text options

Tags: wpf, text, blur

After clicking, for example, on a button with no handler (that is no any reation axcept button clicking animation) I have this ugly effect on my eyes:

[image: image1]
[image: image2]

Blurring of the text on the button goes off in a second (from the first picture to the second and so on to the sharpness), then the text gets sharpness. I have this effect at any combinations of "TextOptions" options in XAML including TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display".

If I click on a button which raises, for example, select file dialog window, everything seems well.

How to escape this blur? Have you ever seen this effect?

In addition. This effect appears only with TextSize=11 and Aero is disabled. With TextSize equals any another value all goes well. But 11 is a default value so everybody can see this bug!

Comment: Same issue here. I'm pretty sure it's a WPF bug. Drives me a bit crazy, to be honest - like I'm loosing my sanity. "Why is the text blurry - oh wait - now it's not" :)

Comment: Additional info. This effect appears only with TextSize=11 and Aero is disabled. With TextSize equals any another value all goes well. But 11 is a default value so everybody can see this bug!

Comment: I have Aero enabled, and it still happens here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you've fixed this yet or not, but the solution is to use the flag `UseLayoutRounding="True"`.  Throw that on the button style and it will be fixed.

Comment: Yeah! I set this property on the window level, and the button inside the deep place of the viewtree was healed from this illness. Thanks.

Comment: What is interesting that this setting is for Silverlight apps and not presented in WPF as is written here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.uselayoutrounding(v=vs.95).aspx But as I wrote before it is really presented in the WPF XAML vocabulary.

Comment: UseLayoutRounding was added to WPF 4.